# Ler arquivo TXT/DAT e fazer parsing antes de salvar no banco de dados (mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho uma aplicação em Ruby on Rails cujo uma das funcionalidades é ler um arquivo de texto com as seguintes extensões "TXT/DAT", para tal, preciso de uma página simples (apenas um campo de input(file) e um botão de submit) para o envio do arquivo, o arquivo em si tem várias linhas que são respostas de uma prova, o arquivo é assim:

```
"EEECBEBABABCEEAACDAEDABCCDDBEAEAEAEABBDBACCACDEBBEDCBEDEBBDCCDCDABBEADDBACEDCEABCDBCCECEED"
```

cada letra é a resposta de uma questão, e a tabela no banco de dados receberá cada registro em uma linha questao/resposta

o que já fiz até agora

Arquivo de rota:

```
get "pages/envio"
post "pages/envio"
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag '/pages/envio' ,multipart: true do %>
    <label for="file">File to Upload</label> <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <div><%= submit_tag 'Process' %></div>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def envio
    @file = params[:file]
    if(@file.respond_to?(:read))
      File.read("#{@file}".to_s, 'r') do |file|
        while line = file.gets
          @gabarito = line[0..line.rstrip.size].split(//)
        end
      end
    elsif(@file.respond_to?(:path))
      File.open(@file) do |file|
        @file = file
      end
      render :envio
    end
end
```

alguma ideia?

Comment: Olá Eugênio, não ficou claro a sua dúvida/problema.

Comment: Oi, Luiz, então é o seguinte, eu tenho vários arquivos em formato .txt e/ou .dat, preciso enviá-los ao sistema (via input), ao apertar  o botão "enviar", preciso que o arquivo seja lido, linha por linha (caso haja mais de uma linha) e que se estiver ok, que aí sim eu possa enviá-los para o banco de dados, onde há uma tabela chamada "gabarito" com os campos questao/resposta

Comment: Ok, mas você enviou esse seu código ai e não falou qual o problema dele, ou o erro ou o resultado.

Comment: como eu disse, preciso ler esse arquivo em formato txt e exibí-lo em uma view, depois que for confirmado que foi lido corretamente é que deve ser salvo no banco de dados

Comment: Ok. Não tem como ajudar. Boa sorte.

Comment: Veja aqui como as telas deveriam ficar, pra você ter uma ideia
dropbox.com/sh/ndhpvmxe0uiupd8/AABKrSe1N4zpNpJwp_h6d-NLa?dl=0

Comment: Adicione as imagens em sua pergunta para que outras pessoas possam ajuda-lo :)

Comment: não tem como, sou novo no stack overflow e não tenho pontos suficientes pra isso, por isso botei no DropBox.